# Shared preferences storing an array,code does not reach the if part

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using shared preferences to store a string like this one: `"hello,hi,watsup,gdni8"` and in the receiver's side I am splitting it by using string.split(",") and storing in an string array.
My code is

```
//isRegistered is just a button check
if(isRegistered) {
    String seperatedByComma=preferences.getString("keysSeperatedByComma","");
    String arrayOfSeperatedStrings[]=seperatedByComma.split(","); 
    for( int j=0;j< arrayOfSeperatedStrings.length;j++) {
        if(message.equalsIgnoreCase(arrayOfSeperatedStrings[i])) {
            flag=1;
            break;                      
        } 
    }

if(flag==1){                                                
    String keymessage=preferences.getString("AutomaticResponse", "");   
    // do action
} else {
    String defaultmessage="i am busy,talk to you later";
    //do action
}
```

That is the kind of code i'm using ,ok if i give a single word for that string "keysSeperatedByComma" like "gdnite",it's reaching and flag is setting to 1.. but if i give something like "gdnite,hi" even though hi is there ,it is not getting reached in if block and else part is executing
"gdnite,gdni8" ,it's not reaching

Comment: When you get your String has it the right value?

Comment: yes it has the right value

Comment: Can you please describe your problem better?

Comment: What king of formatting is this ?? -1, till you correct it (hint: leave no horizontal scrollbar or blank lines)

Comment: i guess i did the formatting @Mr_and_Mrs_D

Comment: You did not actually - but you tried. If you don't improve your formatting you will be laughed at by any serious programmer. All IDEs have automatic formatting (eclipse: Ctrl+Shift+F). USE IT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for( int j=0;j< arrayOfSeperatedStrings.length;j++){

if(message.equalsIgnoreCase(arrayOfSeperatedStrings[j]))//instead of [i] replace it with [j]
{
flag=1;
break;
                                                                                                }


}
```

try this code

Comment: i can't believe i did this simple mistake ... urgh

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the `Array` requisite is an imposed requirement, but if you could use `Set`, this would be perfectly possible.

Since API level 11 and higher, it implements `getStringSet()`. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29).

So basically you may define a `Set<String>`, work with them and store the whole structure. Afterwards, you can recover it by using this method.